# Display a specific master page by a URL

Tags: 2013, master-page

Is there some way to simply use a URL (or other method) to force a page to load with a certain master page, without actually changing the default master page? I'm basically looking to tuck some admin controls away but still be able to easily access them without changing the master page everyone else sees during business hours.

Comment: I think it would be better to security trim the elements you need to hide. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj822366(v=office.15).aspx

Comment: I've had limited success with that for reasons I can't explain so this is actually a work-around for security trimming.

Comment: I understand, what come's to my mind then is if you could somehow use Device channels and associate different Master Pages to each channel.. Just a thought. Maybe you can assign one Master Page to the users default browser, and assign another to another browser that you can use for administrative tasks?

Comment: The master page is actually a responsive design (not using device channels) because people actually access the site from various size screens, so I think that might be out of the question too... but a very clever idea none-the-less!

Comment: Well, then to the goofy method.. hide the controls you need to hide with a custom CSS style sheet and save the Url in your favorites to go there.. Gone, but not inaccessible.. Works if it's a small farm and not to curious users. :)

Comment: if you just edit the master page but don't publish it, your are able to see it in the edited way but all other don't see it unless you publish it. but be sure to make a backup before you change it.